# How do I copy data in LInux in chunks and with timed breaks?

Tags: linux

I have a hard drive with a bad PCB board. It stays on when not under heavy load and it will restart if I copy too much data off it. So far I have had good luck doing folders under 500 MB in size if I copy one folder to my good hard drive, wait five minutes, copy another, etc.

If I mount the bad drive and try to copy a folder of several GBs in size it will start and then stop as the hard drive restarts. When I try to mount the drive again Linux says it can't read the superblock. I have several folders with over 30 GB of data in many different folders.

What I am looking for is a way of copying a folder in Linux such that the commands grab the whole folder in chunks with a timed break in-between.

Answer (score 4):

You could stop the copy process after some time:

```
cp -R srcdir destdir &
sleep 10
kill -STOP $PID_OF_CP
sleep 10
kill -CONT $PID_OF_CP
```

Answer (score 3):

If a slow transfer (i.e. no pauses, but low data rate) will work, then something like this should do. The `tar` commands pack all the files into one data stream, and the `pv` command limits the data transfer rate of that stream.

```
tar cf - <source> | pv --rate-limit 1m | (cd <destination> && tar xf -)
```

I haven't tested this myself, so the syntax may be a little off.

Answer (score -1):

you may first minimize the file weight to be transfered by using the maximum gzip compression, then rsync the tarballs with a timeout option. Also you can run rsync a second time in case your nice disk fade out. Rsync would look at the files in both locations and copy the difference : it would continue the copy from the point the sync was interrupted.